# Rails - Devise / User registration route / POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm stuck a bit with the following problem: I use Devise in Rails, when I open the sign up form and submit it with new the data for the new user, no new user is created in the sqlite-db. I think it's because the POST-route for /register is not properly set:

```
rake routes:
                    root        /                         static#home
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                         devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /register(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /                         devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                         devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

How should I update routes.rb, maybe only :path_names with adding POST for register in some way?:

```
root to: 'static#home'
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

RegistrationsController in Devise(from the devise-homepage, just the default one):

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      yield resource if block_given?
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_flashing_format?
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  def cancel
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    redirect_to new_registration_path(resource_name)
  end

  protected

  def update_needs_confirmation?(resource, previous)
    resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) &&
      resource.pending_reconfirmation? &&
      previous != resource.unconfirmed_email
  end

  # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
  # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_with_password(params)
  end

  # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
  # temporary session data to the newly created user.
  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
  end

  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up. You need to overwrite this method
  # in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    respond_to?(:root_path) ? root_path : "/"
  end

  # The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    signed_in_root_path(resource)
  end

  # Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", :force => true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
  end

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
  end

  def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  end
end
```

new.erb.html:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: can you add your `registrations` controller?

Comment: @dax, I added the source for RegistrationsController above, it's just the default from devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the order in which you are defining routes. Move the root method after devise_for and it should work as intended.

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
root to: 'static#home'
```

If you see [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/root), the root method internally uses map. Since you are specifying root path before devise routes, post requests to root path are being processed by home action of static controller.